# Stop a method in java

Tags: java

I have made a method to send an e-mail, and I wanted to try if it was possible to call a method inside the method itself with a timer, to do like a scheduler

```
public void createExcel(){
        int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int num_week = data.getCurrentWeek()-1;
        ArrayList<DHDemande> ListeDemandes = d.getDemandesForPaie(num_week, year);
        try {
            data.createFile(ListeDemandes);
            Thread.sleep(20000);
            createExcel();
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
```

But now the method doesn't stop (it was obvious) but even if I refresh Apache and if I change the method. How can I stop it ? because I receive an email every 20 second now

Answer (score 0):

The thing with Treads is that there is now save way to tell it to just stop without memory leaks. You can use `thread.stop()`, this will kill the thread but it may cause memory problems if your objects are too big.

Quote from java doc:

> `stop()` Deprecated.  This method is inherently unsafe. Stopping a
>   thread with Thread.stop causes it to unlock all of the monitors that
>   it has locked (as a natural consequence of the unchecked ThreadDeath
>   exception propagating up the stack). If any of the objects previously
>   protected by these monitors were in an inconsistent state, the damaged
>   objects become visible to other threads, potentially resulting in
>   arbitrary behavior. Many uses of stop should be replaced by code that
>   simply modifies some variable to indicate that the target thread
>   should stop running. The target thread should check this variable
>   regularly, and return from its run method in an orderly fashion if the
>   variable indicates that it is to stop running. If the target thread
>   waits for long periods (on a condition variable, for example), the
>   interrupt method should be used to interrupt the wait. For more
>   information, see Why are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and Thread.resume
>   Deprecated?.

Explore the [Thread api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) and see if you can find anything else that suites your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As Borislav mentioned, stop() is incorrect here, you need to call and handle interrupt().

```
class Test
{
    public static Thread helloWorldLater()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override public void run()
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    System.out.println("Hello World");
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    // clean up here
                    return;
                }               
            }
        });
        t.start();
        return t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Thread t = helloWorldLater();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        t.interrupt();
        // no "Hello World" to be seen
    }
}
```

Alternatively, depending on your Java version, you can also use the more modern concurrency Java APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Borislavs and Konrads legitimate comments on `thread.stop()`, you are calling the `createExcel()` method recursively (after `Thread.sleep(20000)`), so obviously your method will run forever. 
If you remove that call it should work like you expect it.

Comment: The thing is, the method doesn't stop, even if I remove createExcel(); and refresh the server

Comment: If you're sure that you've redeployed it to apache (I assume you mean tomcat), then maybe it's due to the way you're calling the createExcel() method. Can you add that code to your question?